# What is wrong with my insert method?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to insert some data to a database. To achieve this i made a method  that returns a `boolean` and receives an `ArrayList` of `Objects` of type `Point`. Everything runs fine until i checked my table and i discovered that it is just one point which has been inserted(the first point each time) although i have a plenty of points(`arrayList.size() > 0`). I can reach for example `arrayList.get(2).getXcoordinate()`if my `arrayList.size(2)`, but my method insert just the first index(`arrayList.size(0)`).
I simply can not figure out where i am doing wrong. Any help or hints is very appreciated. Thanks, Carl - 
My method:

```
public boolean insertPoints(ArrayList<Point> arr) {
       try {
            con = this.getConnection();
            st = con.createStatement();
            if (con != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
                    String id = arr.get(i).getId();
                    String x = arr.get(i).getXcoordinate();
                    String y = arr.get(i).getYcoordinate();
                    if (st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO table (Id, X, Y)
                                 VALUES (" + id + "," + x + "," + y + ")") > 0)
                        return true;
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                System.err.println("No connection, con == null ...");
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null) rs.close();
                if (st != null) st.close();
                if (con != null) con.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                System.err.println("SQLException: " + sqle.getMessage());
            }
        }
         return false;
     }
```

Comment: Why don't u make the method of type `void`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public boolean insertPoints(ArrayList<Point> arr)
    {
        try
        {
            con = this.getConnection();
            st = con.createStatement();
            if (con != null)
            {
                boolean success = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
                {
                    String id = arr.get(i).getId();
                    String x = arr.get(i).getXcoordinate();
                    String y = arr.get(i).getYcoordinate();
                    if (st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO table (Id, X, Y) VALUES (" + id + "," + x + "," + y + ")") > 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        success = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return success;
            }
            else
            {
                System.err.println("No connection, con == null ...");
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (rs != null) rs.close();
                if (st != null) st.close();
                if (con != null) con.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException sqle)
            {
                System.err.println("SQLException: " + sqle.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: this is smart. Thanks for your help. I want to thank everyone too.

Answer (score 2):

This code is not the way you should do this.

Please use `PreparedStatement` to bind variables.

Your `Connection` and `PreparedStatement` should not be class members.  The Connection should be instantiated elsewhere and passed in.

The `PreparedStatement` should have local scope.

You should close resources in individual try/catch blocks in the finally method.  Write static methods to reuse and keep the code small.

You might also consider batching these calls so you INSERT all points in a single round trip.  It'll be more performant.

```
// Your table's name is table?  Terrible.
private static final String INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO table(Id, X, Y) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
```

Answer (score 1):

The following:

```
if (st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO table (Id, X, Y) VALUES (" + id + "," + x + "," + y + ")") > 0)
    return true;
return false;
```

will exit the method after inserting the first value, returning either true or false based on the return of `executeUpdate`.

Maybe something more like this instead

```
 for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
      String id = arr.get(i).getId();
      String x = arr.get(i).getXcoordinate();
      String y = arr.get(i).getYcoordinate();
      if (!st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO table (Id, X, Y) VALUES (" + id + "," + x + "," + y + ")") > 0)
          return false;
 }
 return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

this is problematic

```
if (st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO table (Id, X, Y)
                                 VALUES (" + id + "," + x + "," + y + ")") > 0)
                        return true;
                    return false;
```

just remove both the return statement  and use a flag or counter